# How to highlight the asset on Autodesk forge viewer

Tags: view, autodesk, forge

Currently we are working to integrate the Autodesk forge Viewer to display the REVIT file in our web application.
Also we are getting the asset details in a json format by using Model Derivative API.
Then extract the asset details from JSON file and store it in the database. Then we bind the asset details in tree view.

On clicking the particular asset in tree view - the selected asset should highlight and zoom in forge viewer.
Kindly share any c# sample code to highlight the selected asset (in custom tree view) in forge viewer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code to highlight the asset

pass the dbID:

this.viewer.fitToView(dbID);

this.viewer.isolate(dbID);